# How to make my page appear on google search, post to twitter, merge my pages?

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I have created 2 facebook fanpages that is "Enfant Family Member" before I have converting my Enfant Kidclub profile to a page last 2 week So, now I have 2 pages!

1. Why is my page "Enfant Kidclub" not displaying in facebook search? And google search still finds only the former facebook profile?
2. Could I merge or delete them and have only 1 page that is Enfant Kidclub?
3. Another problem is I set my former page, Enfant Family Member to redirect to my twitter account. Now I want my Enfant Kidclub to post to twitter instead of that one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Why my page "Enfant Kidclub" is not displaying in facebook search? and google search, it  still discover only the former facebook profile?

Results from Facebook website should be in search results by default. I searched for "Enfant Kidclub" and your page is first result. Google auto corrects search to be "Enfant Kid club" which you have to revert

> Could I merge or delete them and have only 1 page that is Enfant Kidclub?

Visit these help pages
[facebook help](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018),
[Another blog](http://www.wearehathway.com/blog/how-to-combine-facebook-pages)

> Another problem is i set my fromer page, Enfant Family Member to redirect to my twitter account. Now I want my Enfant Kidclub to post to twitter instred of that one. Is it possible?

Just try linking your twitter account to new facebook page